# LaTeX graphical lines for domain results

Tags: tabularx, sourcecode

As usual I have a problem with LaTeX code; this time is to show the results of domains interval for example when I have a rational function and I have to split domains into the Numerator one and the Denominator one and take the common range.

Like in photo below. I, again, searched for that on the internet but I found nothing :(

[image: This is what I would get]

Clearly other symbols hold well too!

By now, this is what I created (for example)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
& & & & $\textcolor{red}{0}$   & & \\
 \hline 
  \\\textsf{N} & & & & & $\longrightarrow$ $\longrightarrow$  $\longrightarrow$  \\
  \\\textsf{D} & &$\longleftarrow$ $\longleftarrow$  $\longleftarrow$ & & & $\longrightarrow$ $\longrightarrow$  $\longrightarrow$   \\\\
  \hline 
\\ \textsf{Result}& & & & & $\longrightarrow$ $\longrightarrow$  $\longrightarrow$  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm not too sure what you exactly want: reproduce these symbols (wavy line and cross)? What about the values $-2$ and $1$. Is the rational function defined?

Comment: @Bernard yes exactly! I would like to have such a table in my LaTeX document. But I cannot find any help with the code. :(

Comment: Oh and thank you so much for the welcome :))

Comment: P.s. Clearly, once I got a code for that, I can modify the code for everything similar that I might need!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Don't you think that if I had even a crumb of idea, I would have wrote it here?

Comment: @Henry: I have a simple solution with `pstricks`, but I can't post it anymore, since it's been put on hold. Is there a place where I could post it?

Comment: @Martin Schröder: Having put the question on hold as unclear seems unfair. The O.P. wants to do something rather unusual, but I think I've understood his request, and I have a solution that I can't post. Would you consider reopening the question?

Comment: @Bernard I don't understand what is that.. I mean: can I decide to re-open the question? How?

Comment: @Bernard if you want, I can ask another question identical to this one, and then I'll delete this one...

Comment: @Henry: I'm afraid you can't even vote for re-opening (your score isn't high enough). I'm not sure asking the same question would be a good method… I'l send a message to all the people who voted to close the question. As far as I know, three votes are enough to re-open. If that doesn't work, we'll see.

Comment: @Bernard All right then, I hope they will re open the question, which (by the way) it didn't seem that terrible to me. On the contrary, it should help lots of people with the same problem..
Thank you!!!

Comment: @Henry: it's been re-opened :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with `pstricks`. It can be compiled with `pdflatex` if you launch it with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\undef{\psline(0,-0.1)(1.25,0.25)\psline(0,0.25)(1.25,-0.1)}
\newcommand{\mydef}[1][1.3]{\psplot[algebraic, plotpoints=100, plotstyle=curve]{0}{#1}{0.12*SIN(24*x) + 0.1}}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, dotsize=2.25pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{r@{\quad}*{3}{m{1.3cm}c}}
          & & $\mathclap{-2} \dotnode(0,-5.5pt){I1}$ & & $\mathclap{1} \dotnode(0,-5.5pt){J1}$ & & \\
        \midrule
        N & \undef & & \mydef[2.9] \\
        \midrule
        D & \mydef & & \undef & & \mydef \\
        \midrule
        Result & \undef & \pnode(0,-5.5pt){I4} & \undef & \pnode(0,-5.5pt){J4} & \mydef
    \end{tabular}
    \ncline{I1}{I4}
    \ncline{J1}{J4}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow that's huge! I tried it but it doesn't work :(
I mean : no errors, but empty output

Comment: Did you compile this very code? And did you enable the switch I mentioned?

Comment: Oh sorry, such a dumb -.- I use TeXPad for Mac, so I had to check in the option to find the shell-escape! Now it works!! :))

Thank you really much, I think I can modify it for the future. Oh a stupid question: how can I make the table larger? I mean bigger, to see it better!

Comment: Change the value `m{1.3cm}` in the table preamble to whatever value you want, and set the unit to another value in the postscript part: the default value is 1cm, so the default `1.3`for the sine function is indeed 1.3cm. Writing `\psset{unit=2cm}` at the beginning of the postscript environment should do the trick to have a length of 2.6cm, for instance.

Comment: Thank you to the infinite. I will definitely have to learn PsTricks..

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to  learn than tikz, because the syntax for pstricks is  the syntax of LaTeX. Many people think it's not compatible with pdflatex, but with the auto-pst-pdf package, this is no more true. And you have all the power of PostScript.